# Как сравнить две базы данных и при несовпадении значений их обновить

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, парсер, simple-html-dom

Есть две база данных в которой две таблицы, статическая и динамическая. В статической лежат основные данные которые нужно обновлять (и которые потом будут подгружаться на отдельную страничку).

В динамическую таблицу заливаются новые данные, которые сравниваются с теми что лежат в статической и если в какой то строке произошли изменения, то нужно перезаписывать эту строку в статической таблице, отправить сообщение на почту о том что в строке с `$name` произошли изменения и после этого очистить динамическую таблицу.

В таблицах есть такие столбцы:

```
id_service - ид который задается автоматически в самой базе (1,2,3,4...)(AUTO_INCREMENT)
name - название товара
dt_up - дата обновления строки (тоже обновляется автоматически в самой базе)
id_shop - задается вручную заранее в php (сейчас везде значение "1")
link - ссылка на товар
```

Сейчас нужно сравнить данные (name и link) динамической таблицы со статической.

Пока что (ниже в коде) после загрузки данных в динамическую таблицу - получаю данные из обеих таблиц, а затем их сравниваю, если все значения равны, процесс прерывается если нет то обновляется статическая таблица.

Как правильно обновить таблицу? Сейчас у каждой строки в таблице есть id_service (с уникальным id для каждой строки), как сделать чтобы по нему определялось что в этой строке было изменение и именно ее нужно обновить?

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM services2";//Динамическая таблица

$result = mysqli_query($sql, $query) or die("Ошибка1 " . mysqli_error($sql)); 
if($result)
{
    while($massiv = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $name[] = $massiv['name'];
        $id_service[] = $massiv['id_service'];
        $link[] = $massiv['link'];
    }
}

$query2 ="SELECT * FROM services"; //Статическая таблица

$result2 = mysqli_query($sql, $query2) or die("Ошибка2 " . mysqli_error($sql)); 
if($result2)
{
    while($massiv1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $name1[] = $massiv1['name'];
        $id_service1[] = $massiv1['id_service'];
        $link1[] = $massiv['link'];

    }
}

if($name1 == $name)
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no".'</br>';

      $go2 = "UPDATE services SET  id_shop='1' name='$a->plaintext', link='$a->href' WHERE id_service='$id_service1'"; 
  if (mysqli_query($sql, $go2)) { 
      echo "Данные обновлены!";
  }   else {
      echo "Произошла ошибка Error: " . $go2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($sql);
  }
}
```

Comment: *В базах данных есть такие столбцы:* Это таблицы, а не базы. *нужно сравнить данные (name и link)* А в коде Вы сравниваете только name - почему? *отправить сообщение на почту о том что в строке с $name произошли изменения* Надо отправить только name? И только для изменившихся записей, про новые или удалённые не надо ничего слать? И всё-таки - какие поля совпадают (указывают, что это одна и та же запись), и какие сравниваем на предмет изменения?

Comment: @Akina 
1. Благодарю, исправил "базы" на "таблицы"
2. Не сравнил link потому что на этапе сравнения name зашел в тупик, решил сравнение link потом дописать, когда будет name обновлятся как нужно (наверное это было не верное решение)
3. Письмо нужно чтобы узнать что произошло изменение, по этому да, $name будет достаточно. Про новые или удаленные даже не подумал... да про них стоит писать.
4. Совпадают поля "id_service" и "id_shop"
Поля "name", "dt_up ", "link" - могут меняться - из них сравниваем "name" и "link".

Comment: не понятно по поводу id_service сейчас я вижу вы его читаете и из динамической таблицы и из статической. В описании сказано, что она автоинкрементна. Но если это так, что между двумя таблицами id могут и не совпадать. Отсюда вопрос, на что все таки ориентироваться при сравнении строк в таблицах (по какому полю понимать что это та же самая запись) ?

Comment: @Mike Благодарю! Прошу прощения, я подумал что id_service будет автоматически задаваться одинаково как для первой так и для второй таблицы. Я могу добавить в таблицы артикул товара "vendor" он будет уникален для каждого товара и не будет меняться в отличии от названия или ссылки - будет всегда одинаковый и в первой и во второй таблице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в вопросе ни хрена не понять, покажу вариант решения на модели.

```sql
-- таблица со "старыми" данными
CREATE TABLE t_static ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- ключ
                        name VARCHAR(32), -- поле, которое идентифицирует объект, 
                                          -- по нему можно сравнивать
                        val INT, -- поле, которое может измениться
                        PRIMARY KEY (id),
                        UNIQUE idx_name (name)
                      );

-- таблица с обновлёнными данными
CREATE TABLE t_dynamic LIKE t_static;
```

Получить записи, которые добавляются:

```sql
SELECT t1.name
FROM t_dynamic t1
LEFT JOIN t_static t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Получить записи, которые изменились (обновляются):

```sql
SELECT t1.name
FROM t_dynamic t1
INNER JOIN t_static t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.val != t2.val
```

Выполнить добавление и обновление:

```sql
INSERT INTO t_static (name, val)
SELECT name, val
FROM t_dynamic 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE val = VALUES(val)
```

Получить записи, которые удаляются:

```sql
SELECT t1.name
FROM t_static t1
LEFT JOIN t_dynamic t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Удалить такие записи:

```sql
DELETE t1.*
FROM t_static t1
LEFT JOIN t_dynamic t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```